# nodeJS Imap takes so much time to fetch emails with attachment

Tags: node.js, imap, webmail

I am trying to create a webmail system with React and nodeJS, and I have no clue as to if I am doing it correctly...
I have searched on Google, and read everything I could, but still have no idea.
I purchased a domain for email, built a mail server with MailEnable, and currently using nodeJs libraries such as Imap, and nodemailer for both sending/receiving emails. Is this a correct way to make a webmail client? or is there a standard way of creating it?

I'm asking this because I'm having so many errors. For example, fetching emails with attachments takes so much time, especially when the file size is big.

and since it is not about reading a list of emails, I need to read the whole message to display email like this

[image]

The code for reading email is as below:

```
const {
    simpleParser
} = require('mailparser');

imap.openBox(box_name, false, () => {
    const criteria = ["uid", no];
    imap.search([criteria], (err, results) => {
        const f = imap.fetch(results, {
            bodies: ''
        });
        f.on('message', msg => {
            console.log("Flags: " + msg.flags);
            msg.on('body', stream => {
                simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
                    // const {from, subject, textAsHtml, text} = parsed;
                    var obj = new Object();
                    obj["parsed"] = parsed;
                    view_data.push(obj);


                });
                f.once('error', ex => {
                    return Promise.reject(ex);
                });
                f.once('end', () => {

                    console.log('Done fetching!');

                });

            });

        })
    })
})
```

I get the correct results. It's just that it is too slow when the email has an attachment file with it.
Would there be any way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that happen with any attachment? Or is the size of the attachment a factor in how slow it is?

Comment: Which imap library are you using?

Comment: @Geshode I think the size is a factor. As the size increases, it gets slower. If the size of the attachment is 1MB, it takes about 5s

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using this library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap

Comment: I do not know the details of that imap library, but you should be able to get the structure of the email which will tell you how many parts (e.g. attachments) it has and what their types and sizes are and then you can download only what you need, not the entire email and not the attachments.  This is a core capability of imap so your library should support that.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you! I will try finding how to do that